X-axis in ggplot2 is showing numeric values in hundreds instead of tens
I am creating a bar chart in ggplot2, but my x-axis is showing the amount of minutes in hundreds instead of tens.
This is my code.
ggplot(data=daily_sleep_diff, aes(x=TimeToFallAsleep))+geom_bar()

This is a sample of my dataset.
sample dataset
And this is the chart it shows. Notice the numeric values on the x-axis.
bar chart
I'm confused as to why this is occurring, as I'd think it would just show the numeric values within the column of TimeToFallAsleep, but I am a noob in R, so there's still a lot for me to learn.

Did you check if max(daily_sleep_diff[,7]) has values in hundreds?

I suspect you have a few large values in your dataset and the x axis breaks are being simplified per the first example.
You could adjust the breaks per the second example using scale_x_continuous().
library(tidyverse)

tibble(TimeToFallAsleep = c(37, 32, 20, 34, 19, 300)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(TimeToFallAsleep)) +
  geom_bar()



tibble(TimeToFallAsleep = c(37, 32, 20, 34, 19, 300)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(TimeToFallAsleep)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 300, 20))


Created on 2024-04-01 with reprex v2.1.0

You could also consider, for example, coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 50)) to "zoom in" on the smaller values. Or scale_x_log10() to spread out the smaller values.
